How to modify metadata for ChromaDB collections?
I am using ChromaDB for simple Q&A and RAG. I want to store some information (as cache) in the collection metadata object. For example, some default settings are related to the collection. I will need to update them now and then based on user settings. The issue is that I want to use cosine distance for similarity search instead of the default L2.
Let's see if I want to modify metadata. The only thing I can find is to call collection.metadata.modify([meta_data_dictionary]). (note. modifying the metadata object directly do not work)
When using the modified method, you have to copy the original metadata and make changes. Cannot make changes to single elements, at least I have not been able to. The issue is then I cannot make changes to metadata, because if I make changes to metadata, even if you setting the same distance function: "hnsw:space": "cosine". You will get the following exception:
ValueError: Changing the distance function of a collection once it is created is not supported currently.
Am I doing anything wrong here?
Some sample code:
import chromadb
client = chromadb.Client()

collection = client.get_or_create_collection(name = "my_collection", metadata={"hnsw:space": "cosine", "other_data": "test1"})
client.list_collections()

colleccollection.modify(metadata={"hnsw:space": "cosine", "other_data": "test2"})`enter 

Result:
ValueError: Changing the distance function of a collection once it is created is not supported currently.
Note:
Modifying metadata directly does not work either, as it may appear that the metadata is changed. However, it won't be saved. I used an in-memory client as an example, but I want to persist changes:
collection.metadata["other_data"] = "test2"
print(collection.metadata) # this will set the value to test 2
collection = client.get_or_create_collection("my_collection")
print(collection.metadata) # this will reset the value to test 1


Based on the ChromaDB documentation https://cookbook.chromadb.dev/core/collections/#cloning-a-collection, directly updating a collection’s HNSW parameters and reindexing is not an option. Instead, the process requires cloning the collection, updating the parameters during the clone, and then replacing the original collection

So, the solution, according to what @morry said is to duplicate your collection with a new metadata:
import chromadb
client = chromadb.Client()

collection = client.get_or_create_collection(name = "my_collection", metadata={"hnsw:space": "cosine", "other_data": "test1"})
new_collection_name = 'cosine'

new_collection = client.get_or_create_collection(
    new_collection_name,
    metadata={"hnsw:space": "cosine", "other_data": "test2"}
)

existing_count = collection.count()
batch_size = 64
for i in range(0, existing_count, batch_size):
    batch = collection.get(include=["metadatas", "documents", "embeddings"], limit=batch_size, offset=i)
    new_collection.add(
        ids=batch["ids"],
        documents=batch["documents"],
        metadatas=batch["metadatas"],
        embeddings=batch["embeddings"],
    )

print(new_collection.count())
print(new_collection.get(offset=0, limit=10))  # get first 10 documents

